# Cpp Code Malfunctioning (showing unexpected numbers)

Tags: c++

This is the program that I wrote to calculate average marks:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

std::cout << "Welcome to the average marks calculator! Enter your marks below separating them with a space: " << std::endl;

//uses cnt to calculate the number of points entered
int val,sum,cnt = 0;

for (; std::cin >> val; cnt++) {

    sum += val;

}

sum /= cnt;

std::cout << "Your average marks are " << sum << " points." << std::endl;

return 0;

}
```

When I run it, it goes something like this:

> Welcome to the average marks calculator! Enter your marks below separating > them with a space:
>
> 70 80 90 80 70 80 80
>
> Your average marks are 85198117 points.

The integer 85198117 is clearly not expected there. I'm sure it was a problem with the code here.

Any help of yours will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `sum` is used uninitialized causing undefined behavior, you should also try to debug your programs prior to asking questions, garbage stored in `sum` should be easily noticeable.

Comment: int val,sum = 0,cnt = 0; would do

Comment: to my knowledge avg = sum / n. also prepare for zero division when the user doesn't specify any numbers

Comment: Thank you! I certainly didn't not notice that right there.
(My debugger didn't work. I'm using [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).)

Comment: It is a good habit to define one variable per line and always initialize them

Comment: `val` should be defined inside for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIX:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

std::cout << "Welcome to the average marks calculator! Enter your marks below separating them with a space: " << std::endl;

//uses cnt to calculate the number of points entered
int val,sum = 0,cnt = 0;

for (; std::cin >> val; cnt++) {

    sum += val;

}

sum /= cnt;

std::cout << "Your average marks are " << sum << " points." << std::endl;

return 0;

}
```

> int val,sum = 0,cnt = 0;

sum has to be initialized by 0 (or any other number) to avoid UNDEFINED.

Thanks to all of the comments!